# (SQLITE) Using operators to update a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
UPDATE XP
SET XP_REQUIRED = (5 * (Levels ^ 2) + (50 * Levels) + 100 - XP_REQUIRED)
```

In brackets after

> XP_REQUIRED =

, you will see the math I'm trying to do. Essentially, I want to make a long database of levels and the required XP for said levels, but this query is not working.

[Full documentation here](https://github.com/Mee6/Mee6-documentation/blob/master/docs/levels_xp.md) on the level system I'm trying to imitate as well as the math required to do so.

Comment: There is no `^` operator in SQLite.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm asking what code to use instead of this.